# Custom sort a list with 3 conditions

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

```
my_list = [[12, 17], [15, 11], [12, 11], [15, 17], [13, 7], [8, 11]
sorted_list = [[12, 17], [15, 17], [15, 11], [12, 11], [8, 11], [13, 7]]
```

I want to sort this list so the second number in the sub-list is ordered largest to smallest, and then afterward, any numbers with the same second number sorted by ones closer to the numbers 13.5 first and ones farther away from them are last. Then if 2 numbers have the same second number, and are equally far away from 13.5, choose the one less than 13.5 if the previous one was more than 13.5 and vice versa, the first pair should start below 13.5
I hope this isn't too confusing so I'm going to reword that

--

Let's say the sublist is `[x, y]`

First priority is to sort them greatest to least by `y` first

Second priority is to sort them by `x` furthest away from 13.5 first

Third priority is to alternate between the lower than and greater than 13.5.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this question as an exercise. My code works but it's not pretty. I am hoping to learn how to improve it. Thank you very much.

```
# sorted_list = [[12, 17], [15, 17], [15, 11], [12, 11], [8, 11], [13, 7]]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
listA = [[12, 17], [15, 11], [12, 11], [15, 17], [13, 7], [8, 11]]
listA = dict(zip([i for i in range(len(listA))], listA))
df = pd.DataFrame(listA).T
df.columns = ['A', 'B']
df['C'] = np.abs(df['A'] - 13.5)
df.sort_values(by=['B', 'C'], ascending=[False, True], inplace=True)
df.drop('C', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.index = [i for i in range(len(df.index))]
sorted_list = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    temp_list = []
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        temp_list.append(df.iloc[i, j])
    sorted_list.append(temp_list)
print('sorted_list = ', sorted_list)
```

---

sorted_list =  [[12, 17], [15, 17], [15, 11], [12, 11], [8, 11], [13, 7]]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to alternate between picking a number higher than 13.5 and one lower than 13.5 when they are equally far away from 13.5:

```
from itertools import cycle
c = cycle((1, -1))
print(sorted(l, key=lambda t: (-t[1], abs(t[0] - 13.5), next(c) * (13.5 - t[0]) > 0)))
```

This outputs:

```
[[12, 17], [15, 17], [15, 11], [12, 11], [8, 11], [13, 7]]
```